# Python Program for Synodic months

Tags: the-moon, python

I am trying to make an astronomical program for celestial bodies in our solar system (and beyond!).

However I want it to show how many Synodic months since New moon. Example: Since last 2022 there happened 0.50794789457 Synodic months.

So is there any API/library to get such data (it's not a necessity that a module would be required)? .

Comment: Do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_month#Synodic_month = 29 d 12 h 44 min and 2.9 s? It's a number that will always be less than about one, correct? Isn't the time between successive new Moons on average one synodic month?

Comment: Yes, @uhoh. I am talking about the same Synodic month. Thanks.

Comment: @uhoh Yes. However I did not find such Library while Googling

Comment: 29d12h44min is the mean length of the month.  The actual time between successive new moons can vary (due to perterbations on the moon's elliptic orbit) by 6h either way

Comment: Thanks, @JamesK. However What causes those Perturbations on the Moon's elliptical orbit? Is it the gravity of other planets?.

Comment: Mostly the gravity of the sun.  If you are serious about any kind of astronomical calculation you need to obtain a copy of  "Astronomical Algorithms" by Jean Meeus. They may not be the be-all-and-end-all of astronomical computation.  But they are everyone's starting point.  Lunar theory, in particular, is complex (far more so than the motion of the planets.)  The Moon's orbit is very significantly non-keplarian.

Comment: If you haven't already, look at astropy, there might be something there that would help with what you're trying to do. Not totally sure though.

Comment: The previously mentioned Astronomical Algorithms book has an algorithm for computing the times of the phases of the moon.  You could use that to compute the time between two new moons, and then compute how far along you are in the current Synodic period.  An implementation of the moon phase algorithm is here: https://www.celestialprogramming.com/moonphases.html .

Comment: As James said, lunar theory is complicated. Wikipedia has some good introductory articles on this topic. Start at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_precession then look at the "See also" links https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_of_the_Moon & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_theory

Comment: Why are you writing this "astronomical program for celestial bodies"? Is it just a learning exercise? How accurate do you want it to be?

Comment: BTW, apart from perturbations, the synodic month length varies because the Earth and Moon orbits are elliptical. The mean anomalistic month is almost 2 days shorter than the mean synodic month, so the speed of the Moon at the time of the Full Moon changes significantly from one Full Moon to the next.

Comment: Thanks, @PM2Ring

Comment: I am making this program so that I can get real-time data and observe Planets and Moons as per their RA, DEC and See the Moon. Moreover though it's usage is currently for non-commercial uses but I want it to be extremely precise

Comment: @PM2Ring What is the accuracy of the Meuss algorithms?

Comment: Thanks, @GregMiller

Comment: @PM2Ring The eccentricity of the Moon is 0.0549 according to NASA

Comment: @GregMiller However the link you shared has the code is in Javascript (I also know Javascript but I want to make this in Python) , So is there any  code for Python?.

Comment: Thanks @JustinT. I will check  Astropy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141868/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-scienceaj).

Comment: If you want the Ra/Dec of the moon and planets, you're making it too complicated.  As you can imagine, there have been a lot of people wanting to do the same thing, and there are many ways to do it.  The Skyfield API in the answer below can do it, and the link I posted above has a few different methods too.

Comment: Thanks, @GregMiller. I already have RA, Dec of planets using the same Skyfield library. I want the Day since last new moon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python Skyfield API can do this.  What follows is a brief python program  that will calculate the fraction of time that has passed between the last and the next New Moon.

```
import pytz
from bisect import bisect
from datetime import datetime, tzinfo, timedelta

from skyfield import api, almanac


def main():

    time_zone = pytz.timezone("UTC")
    time = time_zone.localize(datetime.utcnow())

    ephemeris = api.load("de421.bsp")
    timescale = api.load.timescale()

    start_ts, end_ts = timescale.utc((time - timedelta(days=30),
                                      time + timedelta(days=30)))

    phase_times, phase_indices = almanac.find_discrete(
        start_ts, end_ts, almanac.moon_phases(ephemeris))

    new_moons = [phase_time for phase_time, phase_index
                 in zip(phase_times.astimezone(time_zone), phase_indices)
                 if phase_index == 0]

    index = bisect(new_moons, time)
    prev_moon, next_moon = new_moons[index-1: index + 1]

    lunation_fraction = (time - prev_moon) / (next_moon - prev_moon)

    print(f"Lunation fraction: {lunation_fraction}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Incredible script! +n! I've never heard of `pytz` or `bisect` but wow how useful. For those new to Python, if you click "install" at https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution you'll get a nice selection of scientific libraries, but you'll have to install [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. However what does Pytz and bisect do?

Comment: @ScienceAJ I use the `pytz` module to turn an ordinary `datetime` object into one that contains time zone information that  `skyfield`'s `timescale` objects are happy with.  `bisect` takes a sorted list,  and a value and returns the index a value would have if you inserted it in its sorted place;  I used it in this case because in the sixty-day timespan  the code searches for New Moons, there's a small chance of finding three.

Comment: @notovny Thanks a lot!. I shall implement the code in my program